# Calling a C++ DLL from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am making a program to control a laser but to do that I need to import a dll into c# and call functions with it. The original program is written in C++ and I just cant figure it out how to do it.
So my questions are:

1. How to import a dll in c#
2. how to call the functions from C++ in c#

To make it a bit more clear to you I've added the code from the C++ program.

```
#include "MarkEzdDll.h"

class CDemoEzdDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:
    CDemoEzdDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);  // standard constructor

    HINSTANCE m_hEzdDLL;//DLLµ÷ÓÃ¾ä±ú

    LMC1_INITIAL       lmc1_Initial;
    LMC1_CLOSE         lmc1_Close;
    LMC1_LOADEZDFILE   lmc1_LoadEzdFile;
    LMC1_MARK          lmc1_Mark;
    LMC1_MARKENTITY    lmc1_MarkEntity;
    LMC1_GETPREVBITMAP lmc1_GetPrevBitmap;

    LMC1_READPORT  lmc1_ReadPort;
    LMC1_WRITEPORT lmc1_WritePort;

    LMC1_SETDEVCFG     lmc1_SetDevCfg; 
    LMC1_SETHATCHPARAM lmc1_SetHatchParam;
    LMC1_SETFONTPARAM  lmc1_SetFontParam;
    LMC1_GETPENPARAM   lmc1_GetPenParam;
    LMC1_SETPENPARAM   lmc1_SetPenParam;
    LMC1_CLEARENTLIB   lmc1_ClearEntLib;
    LMC1_ADDTEXTTOLIB  lmc1_AddTextToLib;
    LMC1_ADDFILETOLIB  lmc1_AddFileToLib;
    LMC1_ADDBARCODETOLIB   lmc1_AddBarCodeToLib;
    LMC1_CHANGETEXTBYNAME  lmc1_ChangeTextByName;
    LMC1_AXISMOVETO        lmc1_AxisMoveTo; 
    LMC1_AXISCORRECTORIGIN lmc1_AxisCorrectOrigin;  
    LMC1_GETAXISCOOR       lmc1_GetAxisCoor;
    LMC1_SAVEENTLIBTOFILE  lmc1_SaveEntLibToFile;
```

in the dialog, there is a button which has this code attached to it:

```
void CDemoEzdDlg::OnButtonRun() 
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    UpdateData();

    if(lmc1_Mark==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }


    lmc1_Mark(FALSE);
    UpdatePrevBmp();
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Mark file finish!")); 
}
```

This is when the laser should start.

How to get this in c#?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to call C++ functions from C# code, or do you want to call C# methods from C++ code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(It was not very clear from your post, but I am guessing you want to call `C++` functions from your `C#` code.)

`PInvoke` is perfect for this. Here is a nice tutorial: [click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

You don't import the DLL in your project settings; instead you call it from your source code. You do have to make sure that the DLL is in the same folder as your project's output (`.exe`) file, of course.

In a nutshell, if you define a C method like this in `foo.dll`:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool __stdcall GetTrue()
{
    return true;
}
```

Then your C# program can declare it like this:

```
[DllImport("foo.dll")]
static public extern bool GetTrue();
```

and simply use `GetTrue()` to call it. (You also need to add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` in the same file)

Of course it gets more complicated when you use data types that differ between C# and C++ (like strings, objects, etc) but the tutorial covers that pretty nicely.

Comment: "define a C++ method" Actually you are defining a C method ;p